# How can I use RecordJs in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, audio, audio-recording

I need to create a  page in wordpress with an audio recorder, after this audio be recorded, I need to send it by mail to me.

know I can record audio with the recorderjs javascript library.

[GitHub RecorderJs](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs)

However I'm not getting implement the example link above

is possible to use RecordJs for this in wordpress? is there any other way?
You guys know any free plugin for wordpress with this audio recorder?

Comment: Flagging as off-topic because you're asking us to find a library, tool, or other off-site resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the way to make a audio recorder using recorderJs lib.
We need only add the files  .js or .css to our wordpress template or plugin using functions  like wp_enqueue_script() and wp_enqueue_style().

For my necessity I created a new wordpress plugin with a audio recorder.

On my main plugin php file, I just added the code bellow

```
function add_resources() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'my-css', plugins_url( 'resources/css/audio-recorder-    plugin.css', __FILE__ ), array(), '1.0' );
   wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', plugins_url(  'resources/css/bootstrap.min.css', __FILE__ ), array(), '1.0' );

   wp_enqueue_script( 'recorder-js', plugins_url( 'resources/js/recorder.js', __FILE__ ), array(), '1.0', false );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', plugins_url( 'resources/js/bootstrap.min.js', __FILE__ ), array(), '1.0', false );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js', plugins_url( 'resources/js/audio-recorder-plugin.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery','jquery-ui-dialog' ), '1.0', false );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_resources', 999 );
```

So and this solved my question, but have another doubt about ajax in wordpress that I'll ask on another moment.

thks